# How do you activate a Statue and what does it do?

Tags: hero-siege

While playing Hero Siege in the first area of the game, I suddenly got this achievement:

> **Odin's Spirit**
>
> Activate a statue

I have no idea what I have done to deserve this, so I would like to know how you actually activate a statue and what exactly it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate all the switches on the map, then a statue awakens and kills enemies.
But not all levels have switches, so in some of them the statues are only decoration.

The switches appear randomly on levels in Act V, which you need DLC for.

Comment: The switches still exist.  They appear randomly in levels on Act V (which you need the DLC for)

Answer (score -1):

in the actual version statues spawn (randomly) after waves. the game tells you so - then you just have to find it.
to activate it, you just have to be close to it for a second.
it will give you a (permanent) buff.

devil-statues may also give you a (permanent) de-buff.

*but i am not really sure what "permanent" means here*

Comment: Permanent means until your run ends. Has been a while since I played the game but I remember that I was avoiding the devil statues as the debuffs could be significant and I did not want to take the risk.

Comment: You forgot that the statues can give items as well. Also, the permanent buff of the Devil-Statue is a lot higher then that of the Holy-Statue, that's probably why it also has the debuff.

Comment: These are not the statues the achievement is referring to